# Can I create Photoshop brushes for foundational elements in designs?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I am early in my experience with creating digital art. I've found a lot of Photoshop brushes that help me get the look and feel that I want for specific design elements, as well as brushes for grass, trees, and hair.

Can I create a Photoshop brush for something like landscape design? For example, a set of brushes that would mimic mountains or hills, rivers or other water, rocks, etc. What are the best practices for creating these brushes?

The idea would be that I could open a new canvas, use these brushes as stamps/placeholders for laying out the landscape, then add layers to provide detail.

Comment: Yes you can create your own custom Photoshop brushes which you could use to stamp with.  Not sure what you mean by "landscape design".  Do you mean digital painting/drawing of landscape scenes?  Or do you mean landscape gardening design?  There may be better software available for this, but this likely outside the experience of graphic designers.  There is a Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange where you might get better advice.

Comment: A Photoshop brush can be created from **any** greyscale image. [Adobe help topic on brush creation.](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-modifying-brushes.html)